# MySQL join for two tables based on on column and excluding the values of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables.

1. Project table
2. Project relationship table

Project table contains all the project IDs and name

```
Id:1, name:project1
Id:2, name:project2
Id:3, name:project3
Id:4, name:project4
Id:5, name:project5
Id:6, name:project6
```

Project relationship table contains parent-child relationship between all the project.

```
parent:1, child:2
parent:1, child:3
parent:4, child:5
```

Here parent and child refers to project IDs. I want a join query to get the list of only parent project along with their child-project count.

Like this

```
Id:1, name:project1, count:2
Id:4, name:project4, count:1
Id:6, name:project6, count:0
```

Comment: Try this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860295/query-with-count-subquery-inner-join-and-group

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck. Also, this is an easily googled faq.

Comment: Hi @philipxy it's not like I haven't tried doing this. I tried this doing this on my own but I came across two cases of I join by child_id and select the null child ids. I would get main project but not the sub project count and if I join by parent_id then the cont will be there but the child I'd will be also there which I don't wanted. Then I thought of doing two joins but that would latter cause performance issue. If u feel like it can be easily googled please do share me the link in next comment. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization. Show any relevant parts you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you want *assuming you do not have relationships nested more than one deep*:

```
select coalesce(pr.parent, p.id), count(pr.child)
from project p left join
     projectrelationship pr
     on pr.child = p.id
group by coalesce(pr.parent, p.id);
```

The `join` is to the *child* in the relationship.  This gives two cases:

- If there are children, then `pr.parent` is the parent id.
- If there are no children, then the `left join` has no match and `p.id` is the parent id.

The `group by` then aggregates by the parent and counts the children from `pr`.

Comment: Ur query answers my question. Thank you. But can u explain how are u restricting the child project [2,3,5]. As I can see u are making only one join.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and explanation. I was breaking my head over doing this in one join but how u have used the coalesce in group by really does the job. Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

This will count the child for projects with no parents.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name,
       COUNT(prC.child) AS childrenCount
FROM projects AS p
LEFT JOIN project_relations AS prC on p.id = prC.parent -- relations to children
LEFT JOIN project_relations AS prP ON p.id = prP.child -- relations to parent
WHERE prP.parent IS NULL -- no relation to a parent found
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```